# Get the window location has and apply class to a matching div

Tags: jquery

As the title says, I'm getting the location hash and storing it in a var. I'm then searching for a link with a name attribute which matches the hash and adding a class to it.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
$('a[name*='+hash+']').addClass("boo");
```

Not having any luck though? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does adding double quotes after the `*=` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine, just drop the star (*) and add quotations to hash:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
$('a[name="'+hash+'"]').addClass("boo");
```